# PHP ldap_add() - constraint violation 19 - homedirectory

Tags: php, ldap

I'm getting an error when creating a new account through php using ldap_add(), it's a strange one as certain names just won't work. The error is constraint violation (19). It's not the size of the name that's the issue as I've tried smaller ones and they are fine. Pulling my hair out with this one.

```
$user = "username";
$psw = "password";
$server = "com-ads-04s.domain.co.uk";
$ds=ldap_connect($server);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3); 
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0); 
$r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw);
$hDrive = "\\\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Affan.Ghani";
$starter_with_space = "Affan Ghani";
$firstName = "Affan";
$lastName = "Ghani";
$starter_with_dot = "Affan.Ghani";
$NewUserAD["homedirectory"] = $hDrive;
$NewUserAD["cn"] = $starter_with_space;
$NewUserAD["sn"] = $lastName;
$NewUserAD["givenname"] = $firstName;
$NewUserAD["objectclass"][0] = "top";
$NewUserAD["objectclass"][1] = "person";
$NewUserAD["objectclass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
$NewUserAD["objectclass"][3] = "user";
$NewUserAD["displayname"][0] = $starter_with_space;
$NewUserAD["displaynameprintable"][0] = $starter_with_space;
$NewUserAD["proxyaddresses"][1] = "SMTP:".$starter_with_dot."@domain.co.uk";
$NewUserAD["userprincipalname"] = $starter_with_dot."@domain.co.uk";
$NewUserAD["mail"] = $starter_with_dot."@domain.co.uk";
$NewUserAD["userprincipalname"] = $starter_with_dot."@domain.co.uk";
$NewUserAD["samaccountname"] = $starter_with_dot;
$NewUserAD["useraccountcontrol"][0] = 544;
$NewUserAD["objectcategory"][0]= "CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
$NewUserAD["name"][0] = $starter_with_space;
$NewUserAD["objectcategory"][0] = "CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
$userWithOU = "CN=".$starter_with_space.",OU=Services,OU=UserDepartments,OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
$NewUserAdded = ldap_add($ds,$userWithOU,$NewUserAD)
```

After some investigation I found it's the `$NewUserAD["homedirectory"]` that's causing it, so I started putting random things in at the username part at the end, so these don't work:

```
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Affan.Ghani
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Maff.Mace
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Maff.Mace1
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Affan.Bo
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Maff.Ghani
```

These do:

```
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Maff1.Mace
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Jo.Bo
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Jo.Ghani
\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Maff1.Ghani
```

Anyone got any ideas?
thank you

Comment: I notice that you have `$hDrive = "\\\\sub.domain.co.uk\Area\users\homefoldersA-B\Affan.Ghani";` ~  so the leading backslashes are escaped but subsequent ones are not. Perhaps escape the others in the homefolder path too?

Comment: I tried that earlier, sorry forgot to mention that, it makes no difference, this is really confusing me! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: From the couple of articles I have just briefly looked at ( https://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/Solutions/10094636.html and http://serverfault.com/questions/420782/descriptive-constraint-violation-when-using-passwd ) this particular error seems to indicate a size issue with the attribute. Have you checked the log files on the DC to see if they show a more detailed error message? Also worth checking the schema in ADSIEdit to see if the attribute size has been adjusted

Comment: @RamRaider I will try and get someone in infrastructure to check the logs, thanks. I thought it was size from everything I've read too, but I can enter shorter names just fine.

Comment: When I interpret it right, you are using AD as the LDAP-Backend. I'm not sure whether there are certain restrictions within AD regarding the homedirectory-names. I notice that the part before the dot is either 2 letters or ends with a number before the dot.